# Slow 3D histogramming with histogrammar - sparksql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, histogrammar

I'm trying to create 3D histograms using [histogrammar](http://histogrammar.org/):

```
val empty = Bin(40, -20, 20.0, $"Ax",
            Bin(40, -10, 20.0, $"Ay",
                Bin(40, -10, 1.6, $"Az")))
```

Sample data:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|         Ax|          Ay|         Ax|
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|      -0.14|0.0099999998|      -0.14|
|      -0.14|0.0099999998|      -0.14|
|      -0.14|0.0099999998|      -0.14|
|-0.20999999|0.0099999998|-0.20999999|
|-0.20999999|0.0099999998|-0.20999999|
|-0.28999999|0.0099999998|-0.28999999|
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

This code compiles and runs; however it is extremely slow compared to 1D histogramming.

Q1: Is my code the way it supposed to?

Q2: The running time should still be linear with respect to the number of rows. Is that the case with histogrammar?

Comment: I haven't performance-tested N-d histograms. The default fill methods must walk down a tree three levels deep for 3-d histograms, as opposed to one level deep for 1-d histograms, so it should be slower, but I'm surprised that it's "extremely" slow. It should absolutely be linear, though.

Comment: @JimPivarski From my observation, the time for 1D histogram < 2D << 3D. I will try again with the RDD API.

Comment: Oh! This isn't the default fill— it's a SparkSQL column expression. But looking at the code... it uses SparkSQL to calculate the quantities and then an RDD aggregate to reduce the quantities to a histogram. Ordinary filling happens inside the RDD aggregate, so it's walking down depth-3 trees.

Comment: I ended up with first bucketize each column, and then using Spark's built-in aggregation.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working for you, and agree that this performance issue is disturbing.